# response.setContentType("APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM")

Tags: java, jsp, content-type

I have a very basic question:

I am writing code to download a CSV file using JSP & Servlets. I got the code from internet forums and it is working fine, but I am trying to understand the significance of the two following lines

```
response.setContentType("APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""
            + filename + "\"");
```

Now the first line `response.setContentType` - According to my understanding it tells the browser what kind of data is expected from the server. My question is **what does it tell the browser with value `application/octet-stream`**. I see this being used for downloading all kinds of files. If this lines informs the browser that page would download a file, **what difference is the next line causing**. `response.setHeader` is having attachment as a parameter.

Can anyone tell me the significance of these 2 lines for file download?

Regards Tarun

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first line describes the datatype.

```
response.setContentType("APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM");
```

`APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM` stands for binary data. It may be more precise by specifing the actual filetype. For images it coud be `image/png`. If the browser knows the exact filetype it may show the file directly.

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
```

This says "Don't even try to show the file, just save the file." It also suggests a filename.

*update*
There is a better explaination of mime-types and content-disposition at wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Disposition

Comment: Wow Wonderfully explained, short and precise. Thanks