# Excel download not working after populating the values in java

Tags: java, angularjs, excel, spring-mvc

In my application using spring and angularjs and java, On clicking a button ,there is an ajax call which fetches the data from db and the data needs to be written to an excel file and the same file needs to be downloaded in the browser itself. I am attaching the code snippet for the same .

Now the problem is, even though the data is being fetched and I am able to bind it as worksheet using poi ,  the excel file never comes in the browser as download.

kindly help me in finding a right solution. Thank You.

```
fileName.append(Calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND));
            fileName.append(oCalendar.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
            Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Transaction" + fileName.toString());
CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
            style.setFont(font);

            Row header = sheet.createRow(0);
            header.createCell(0).setCellValue("Name");
            header.createCell(1).setCellValue("ACC");
            header.createCell(2).setCellValue("Date");
            header.createCell(0).setCellValue("TRANSACTION_RECONCILIATION_IDENTIFIER");
            header.createCell(1).setCellValue("ORIGINAL_RECONCILIATION_IDENTIFIER");
            header.createCell(2).setCellValue("STR_TRANSACTION_Date");
   response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"TransactionDetails.xls\"");
 OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
                                             workbook.write(outputStream);
```

Answer (score 0):

After writing the output stream you should use 
    response.flushBuffer();

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing the contentType definition.  Before calling the write() method try setting the contentType like this:

`response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");`

This should tell the browser that a download is expected from the server.  A relevant question was asked here: [response.setContentType("APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23252458/response-setcontenttypeapplication-octet-stream)

In my code I write like this:

```
response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                "attachment; filename=TransactionDetails.xls");
workbook.write(response.getOutputStream());
```

Hope this helps