# Require to get linux environment parameter values in java

Tags: java, linux

I am using tomcat on Linux for my web portal. I need to use the home path of the environment. But when I try to get the home path it gives me the home path of tomcat user. I need home path for a different user.
I am using the below code to get the environment values and get the value of HOME from it

```java
Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
homePath=env.get("HOME").toString();
```

It is giving me the output as below

> HOME=/home/tomcat

Where as I require as below

> [ant00devc_i02]/data/a00dc $ echo $HOME
>   /data/a00dc
>   [ant12devc_i02]/data/a00dc $

Where `a00dc` is a different Linux user.

Comment: Would the tomcat user even have access to the other user's home directory?

Comment: Currently it does not have but would be possible. We can ask infra team to provide the access.

Comment: Well, it probably shouldn't have. What exactly are you trying to do? Can't you use a dedicated directory instead and configure that somewhere (e.g. via a commandline or system property)?

Comment: Thanks Thomas for your response.My requirement was to create some report and store it as a file on a Linux server. I was thinking of storing it into the user location which we generally use to login into the server. Currently I am storing the files in a directory under tomcat user only.
Now the next requirement is to create a downloadable option for users.
The file will be shown on UI, and user should be able to download the file from Linux server and save it in their local system.
Can anyone please suggest the process.
Please advise if I need to post the requirement as a different post.

Comment: Well, to download the file the tomcat user would need to have access to it. Generally I'd not store "shared" files (that other users on the machine should have access to as well) in home directories but in some explicitly shared directory, e.g. somewhere in /var. For the download you'd need to read the file and return the byte stream to the user - there are plenty of tutorials on how to do that but the exact details would depend on what web framework you're using - if any.

Comment: Thanks !! Actually the file owner would be tomcat user only. And yes I am.now able to download the file as well. Accessing the file using fileInputStream to read from file and write using response.getWriter. 
Before writing I am setting below two response configurations

`response.setContentType("APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM");
  response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""+ fileName + "\"");`
I got this reference from below URL
[link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23252458/response-setcontenttypeapplication-octet-stream.
Thanks again for your help :)